# Is it possible to create an initializer_list from an enum?

Tags: c++, enums, default, initializer-list

Is it possible to declare a static initializer_list with elements in an enum, without explicitly declaring it, in order to use it as default argument? Example:

```
#include <initializer_list>   
#include <iostream>

enum ID {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
};


inline constexpr std::initializer_list< ID > all { A, B, C, D };

void func(const std::initializer_list< ID >& args = all) {
    for (const auto& arg : args) {
        std::cout << arg << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    /* code */
    func();  // prints 'all' contents
    return 0;
}
```

However, I would like to avoid having to explicit declare an `ID` list in two places. I understand I could use a `std::vector` for that purpose:

```
#include <initializer_list>   
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

enum ID {
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    // ...
    MAX = D
};



inline std::vector< ID > all() {
    std::vector< ID > list(ID::MAX + 1);
    for (int i = ID::A; i <= ID::MAX; i++) {
        list[i] = static_cast< ID >(i);
    }
    return list;
}


void func(const std::vector< ID >& args = all()) {
    for (const auto& arg : args) {
        std::cout << arg << std::endl;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    /* code */
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

but I am curious if it is possible to implement this with `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: *"I would like to avoid having to explicit declare an ID list in two places. I understand I could use a `std::vector` for that purpose"* Not sure what you mean here. No reflection so  you have to list enum value (or, if values are contiguous, use some kind of `iota` with first and last value). I don't see how `std::vector` solve something here.

Comment: I mean that I could have a static `all()` function that returns a `std::vector<ID>` (assuming enum values are sequential, one can just iterate and append them to a vector). An `initializer_list` lacks that kind of functionality.

Comment: I believe what you search for is reflection. C++ still did not have it...

Comment: C++ has very limited introspection functionalities. A lot of people have been asking for the ability to get a list of values an enum defines but it has not yet been added to the language. There are some work around using macros but in general you will find enumerating the values in the definition and then again in a separate list of values.

Comment: I do not think there is a construct in the standard library that makes this possible, but you could probably write your own function similar to std::make_integer_sequence, but for initializer_lists.

Comment: I see 3 uses of the letters `ID` in your code.  Are you looking to remove 1, 2 or 3 of those uses?  Or are you looking to remove the duplicate `A,B,C,D` part?  Please be really explicit with what your problem is.

Comment: It's very unclear how a `std::vector` would change anything. There is no "`initializer_list` enumerating all values of this type" functionality for any type.

Comment: @joaocandre `std::initializer_list` does not hold the underlying `const` array (see it as a pair of iterators). This makes it an unsuitable structure for your use case. You better have to stick with a `std::vector` (assuming the enum values are contiguous, which is the case in your example).

Comment: What is the reason to have something like this? Are you trying to convert enumeration into string representation, for example to print enum names?

Comment: The code in the question is intended to provide an example use case. The purpose is to get a simple & verbose way to have a default value for the initializer list argument, without having to explicitly declare a potentially large list at each function call.

Comment: @molbdnilo I guess OP meant hardcoding it [with a for loop](https://godbolt.org/z/qfWsYW5Mc)

Comment: There are some libraries which add reflection to enum through MACROs (as [better-enums](https://github.com/aantron/better-enums))

Answer (score 2):

```
enum IDs {
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D,
  ENUM_COUNT,
};

template<class E>
using enum_indexes_t = std::make_index_sequence<static_cast<std::size_t>( E::ENUM_COUNT )>;
template<class E>
constexpr enum_indexes_t<E> enum_indexes_v = {};

template<class E, std::size_t...Is>
constexpr auto enum_list( std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
  return std::integer_sequence<E, static_cast<E>(Is)... >{};
}
template<class E>
constexpr auto enum_list() {
  return enum_list<E>( enum_indexes_v<E> );
}


template<class Es>
struct to_initializer_list;
template<class E, E... es>
struct to_initializer_list< std::integer_sequence<E,es...> > {
  static inline constexpr std::initializer_list<E> list = {es...};
};

template<class E>
constexpr auto enum_il_v = to_initializer_list< decltype( enum_list<E>() ) >::list;
```

then `enum_il_v<IDs>` is an initializer list referencing a global-scope array containing A through D.

The keys here are (a) `ENUM_COUNT` a "famous" end of enum we add to the enum, and (b) the elements of the enum are contiguous from 0 up to `ENUM_COUNT` but not including.

You can work around `ENUM_COUNT` by adding a different way to get the count.  There is no practical way to work around the need for the elements to be contiguous, unless they match some other simple known pattern, using this technique.

Other alternatives include waiting for reflection to arrive in C++, or use of macros or other preprocessing techniques (like code generation).

Comment: I'd be tempted to use `std::underlying_type_t<E>` instead of `std::size_t` here

Comment: @caleth size_t is needed for index sequence, and make index sequence is implemented as a compiler intrinsic so much faster than doing it manually.  But make integer sequence exists.